# RetrieveMultiple query on team security roles

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on a plugin event using the Plugin Registration Tool and CRM Dynamics SDK that needs to check the security roles for the logged in user.

I've found plenty of examples and documentation on retrieval of user roles assigned specifically to the user but I also need to retrieve the security roles assigned to the teams the user is a member of.

I have the list of teams the user is a part of via a separate RetrieveMultiple query but I have been unable to find documentation on the relationship between teams and their assigned security roles.

I have the following incorrect query but as the security role to team relationship is many to many, I would assume there is a relational entity that I am missing for the query:

```
CrmService.RetrieveMultiple(new QueryExpression
            {
                LinkEntities =
                {
                    new LinkEntity
                    {
                        LinkFromEntityName = "role",
                        LinkFromAttributeName = "roleid",
                        LinkToEntityName = "???",
                        LinkToAttributeName = "roleid",
                        LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
                        {
                            FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                            Conditions =
                            {
                                new ConditionExpression
                                {
                                    AttributeName = "teamid",
                                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                                    Values = {p_team.Id}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                EntityName = "role",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
            });
```

It seems like this would be a straight forward query on the team but I've turned up empty on my Google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*teamroles* is what are you looking for.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309538.aspx) is complete list of N:N tables for default entities